# How to update a User's Current Status using the SCIM API?

Tags: slack-api, scim, slack-scim

I'm attempting to update a User's [Current Status](https://api.slack.com/docs/presence-and-status#custom_status) field using the SCIM API. I'm aware this field can be updated using the `users.profile.set` POST [API](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.profile.set#http_request__updating-a-users-current-status). How can I update the `profile` block of a user object using the SCIM API? I looked through the [user attributes](https://api.slack.com/scim#scim-api-endpoints__users__user-attributes) supported by the SCIM API, but I do not see `profile` block or the nested fields such as `status_text`, `status_emoji`, `status_expiration` in this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** set `presence` using SCIM apis.

 **SCIM** APIs for **Users** work only on **User Attributes**

> **User Attributes**
>
>  Attributes are the details associated with a user's account. These are the details that someone would typically set in their profile (for example, by clicking the Edit Profile button in the Slack application).

https://api.slack.com/scim#scim-api-endpoints__users__user-attributes

To set 'User Presence' you'll need regular slack APIs but that would need the user's token.

Comment: thank you! A follow up - under the hood do Apps, such as Outlook or Google Calendar, also use the regular Slack API to update my `presence`or do they use something else?

Comment: I believe when you use such apps, each user have to individually configure the app and maybe then they acquire the user token. Your question is very relevant and I'll try to look more into it. Meanwhile you can ask slack support for more info.

Comment: I checked with Slack support, this is what I heard back from them:
_User Status does not map to a SCIM attribute, and so can only be adjusted using `users.profile.set`. Other Apps which update this field, including the Google and Outlook Calendars, do indeed use the `users.profile.set` method to update user status. Even updating your Slack Status manually through the UI actually triggers a call to the `users.profile.set` endpoint to update this._

Comment: Since what I answered is same as what slack mentioned. I’ll appreciate if you mark my answer as accepted. Thank you.